# SetForegroundWindows optional captionName

Tags: c#

I have this code, I would like to match any CaptionName, I don't really know what to do, and how I can put a regex or maybe an other thing, so it can check any CaptionName that I want to use with the BringToFront method.. Take a look :

```
class Program
{
    [DllIport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    private static void BringToFront(string className, string CaptionName)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(FindWindow(className, CaptionName));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        BringToFront("Notepad","#*#");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You can get process handle by filter all process get from Process.GetProcesses(), and then get handle.

Invoke SetForegroundWindow to show them to foreground.

```
class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        private static void BringToFront(string CaptionName)
        {
            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses()
                                         .ToList()
                                         .FindAll(/*Write your rule here*/p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(CaptionName)))
            {
                SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BringToFront("Notepad");
        }
    }
```